# Office 365 subscription: Associate Azure AD Application created for OAuth

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am a bit confused with Office 365 subscriptions and the application I have created in Azure AD for OAuth.

I have programmatically created an Azure AD app for OAuth and have assigned it appropriate permissions for Graph API and EWS API. The app is working perfectly fine with the Dev tenant I have for my testing. I am able to programmatically access OneDrive and Mailboxes using the token created by this application.

Now I am not sure if I need to associate this app with Office 365 subscriptions. Currently, my dev tenant does not have any Azure / Office 365 subscriptions but users in the field may have Azure / Office 365 subscriptions.

I am not sure if I need to perform any specific checks for subscriptions and associate my app with any. Information I found on the net is confusing and I am unable to conclude anything from it.

Please let me know if you have any idea about this. I am a bit new to this whole thing so forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Graph API and EWS API only requires that you have O365 subscription.

But you don't need to do something like associating with O365 subscription.

Just make sure this Azure AD application is available in the corresponding tenant.

For example, we have a tenant `@testTenant.onmicrosoft.com`, and a user `admin@testTenant.onmicrosoft.com`.

You need to create the AAD application in this tenant `@testTenant.onmicrosoft.com`. And if `admin@testTenant.onmicrosoft.com` has O365 subscription with Exchange Online license, you can access its AAD user profile information and O365 mailbox with Graph and EWS. If the user doesn't have O365 subscription, you can also access its AAD user profile information. But the mailbox is not existing so you can't access the mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was a bit confused with the AAD app, OAuth, and O365 subscriptions. But it looks like the purpose of the AAD app is just to help with OAuth and not interfere with subscriptions.